# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error occurs in Thrift in Java

Tags: java, thrift

I'm starting to use the Thrift framework, basic examples are successful, only when I try to make an application more methods is occurring error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Below the exception thrown.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
 heap space org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: connecting failed:
 out of sequence response   
 at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:379)
 at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readString(TBinaryProtocol.java:374)
 at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:225)
 at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:27)
 at br.com.gadje.servico.client.CollectorReceiver.run(CollectorReceiver.java:32)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am beginning the client side TTransport as follows:

```
 TTransport transport = new TSocket (server, port);
 Protocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol (transport);
```

Comment: Did you try to run the JVM with greater memory allocation?

Comment: java -Xms=512m -Xmx=512m. Use the value that suits your needs.

Comment: I am specifying the Xmx and Xms JVM. Looking at the code Thrift error occurs in TBinaryProtocol class in readStringBody method when it will initialize a byte vector.I do not know why but the size being passed on startup is too great.

Comment: what is the size?  have you looked via the debugger?

Comment: There are two typical cases leading to that effect: (1) The server uses `TFramedTransport` explicitly or implicitly(some server types require `TFramedTransport`) but the client does not. (2) You are really trying to transport way too much data.

Comment: There may be some corruption is the data resulting in read of size incorrect (and size read as a much bigger value). When trying to allocate that, JVM may be throwing the out of memory error

Comment: @NipunTalukdar: I was guessing as well, but yours is a really wild guess. May be the case though, but very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the `OutOfMemoryError` occurs when your server is using `TBinaryProtocol` but you try to access it in another way, e.g. using a browser (which speaks HTTP). Maybe that is your problem as well?

In case you want to access your Java server using a Javascript client, have a look at this sample: https://github.com/LukeOwncloud/ThriftJavaJavascriptDemo